# PHP GD avatars go blank when certain images are put in it

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm making an avatar site. One of my users is having an issue... their avatar is going blank. Their avatar:

http://www.world2build.com/API/Avatar.aspx?ID=1586

The items on their avatar work fine without this item, but when they put this body on, which is the very first layer, it goes blank:

http://node1.world2build.com/Body/13245107086553.png

However, if I move the Body to the top layer, it displays... but I have to keep the body at bottom layer to make sure it displays like a normal avatar. Why would this make the PNG go blank with it as the bottom layer? I don't see the problem.

Code (with $vars being an array with the links to the files):

```
function merge_image($base, $img){
    $width = imagesx($img); 
    $height = imagesy($img); 
    imagecopy($base,$img,0,0,0,0,$width,$height);
}

$base = imagecreatefrompng($vars[0]);
for($i=1; $i<count($vars); $i++){
    merge_image($base, imagecreatefrompng($vars[$i]));
    //echo $vars[$i]."<BR>";
} 

header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
imagesavealpha($base, true); 
imagepng($base);
```

NOTICE: $base, on line 7, is the body image (the one causing the problem.)

A working avatar is: http://www.world2build.com/API/Avatar.aspx?ID=1602 (it uses a different body than the one provided above)

Comment: Please provide a working example with complete code and the images to tinker with.

Comment: imagealphablending($base,false); imagesavealpha($base,true);   ??

Comment: I provided the complete code, except for the $vars which is just an array of the image files, e.g. "../Images/body.png" (all file Urls are valid.) i'll update with a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by replacing the code with this, and turning $base into a blank image.

```
$base = imagecreatefrompng("../Images/BlankTransparentImage.png");
for($i=0; $i<count($vars); $i++){
    merge_image($base, imagecreatefrompng($vars[$i]));
    //echo $vars[$i]."<BR>";
}
```

(Notice I changed $i=1 to $i=0 in the for loop to include the body.)